# What is the purpose of close console in STS/Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In STS/Eclipse there is an X on the console menu, the hint menu displays this as "Close Console". When you click it, the console closes. However, if you are running a process, like a web server, in the STS/Eclipse IDE, the process continues to run. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to re-open this console. It seems like once it's closed, it's gone. The only way to kill any running process in the IDE is to restart the IDE.
What the heck is it supposed to do/solve?

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this menu and X item/button that you're talking about?

Comment: Added screen shot. When you hover over the X in the red box, the hint says "Close Console"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug:  https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4138

> Kris De Volder (c) added a comment - 11/Jun/15 3:18 PM
>
> **I uninstalled
>   CF tooling and the button is gone**. Culprit identified.
>
> Kris De Volder (c) added a comment - 12/Jun/15 1:07 PM - edited
>
> Nieraj tells me he has pushed a fix. Also there was a pivotal tracker issue
>   created for this: 
>   https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1027166/stories/96902200

Edit: Tested this myself, went to *Help -> About Spring Tool Suite -> Installation Details*. In the first tab that opens (*Installed Software*), I chose "**Cloud Foundry Integration for Eclipse**", clicked *Uninstall* and after it completed & restarted STS, the extra Close-button's gone. It was super annoying, as I kept sometimes hitting it on accident and needed to restart everything to get back going (even though the process was still running and you could see it in, for example, debugger, there was no way to get the console back without restart).